# Приходит ответ без нужного блока

Tags: php

Есть функция парсинга количества страниц в индексе Google

```
if ( ! function_exists('google_index')) {
function google_index($domain)
{
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site:'.$domain;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)) {
        return 'N/A';
    }
    parseResults($html);
}

function parseResults($html) {
    @preg_match('#<div.*?id="resultStats"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div[^>]*>#siu', $html, $matches);
    if(isset($matches)) {
        $withoutTags = @preg_replace('/<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>/siu', '', $matches[1]);
        $num = @preg_replace("/\D/u", "", html_entity_decode($withoutTags));
        return (float) $num;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Но ответ приходит без этого блока, хотя он есть на странице поиска

```
<div id="resultStats">Приблизное количество результатов: 29&nbsp;100<nobr> (0,30 сек.)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

И есть сайт, где все это работает

Answer (score 0):

Установка опций CURLOPT_USERAGENT решила вопрос